# Why not 2, 3, 4, or more photons can be absorbed by single electron?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, photoelectric-effect

During Photoelectric effect and other such phenomenon, when light is made to fall on metal surface, single photon is absorbed by the single electron present in metal atom. Why not 2, 3, 4, or more photons can be absorbed by single electron?

Comment: multiple absorption is possible in principle, but *way* less probable.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a duplicate, but it's a perfectly good question.

Comment: See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/225255/does-laser-light-with-less-than-the-work-function-still-ionise-some-atoms/225258#225258

Comment: Since the advent of high power lasers multiphoton ionization of atoms has become an active area of research. Google with "multiphoton ionization"